# Knowing screen coordinate in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

How to know the coordinate of right hand side bottom of the scrren during runtime ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const QRect QDesktopWidget::screenGeometry(int screen = -1) const`

[Docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopwidget.html#screenGeometry).

Comment: Is there any way to know the coordinates of bottom right corner of the application ?
Means whether you are doing minimize or maximize it should give you the bottom right corner coordinates of the application .

Comment: Your post asked about the screen coordinate, now you are asking about the application's top-level widget?  They are not the same thing.  Simply calling `<top-level widget>::geometry().bottomRight()` will give you that.